# Postgresql function to C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, openstreetmap, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to calculate the given tile a node is in from OpenStreetMap so that I can manually add nodes directly into the current_nodes table. If I want to add a new node at latitude X and longitude Y, I can then calculate the 'tile' value that's needed before inserting into the current_nodes table.

I'm trying to convert the current PostgreSQL function into C# but it's not giving the output expected. I'm not sure I've converted it correctly or if I'm missing something.

```
//maptile_for_point(scaled_lat bigint, scaled_lon bigint, zoom integer)
DECLARE
  lat CONSTANT DOUBLE PRECISION := scaled_lat / 10000000.0;
  lon CONSTANT DOUBLE PRECISION := scaled_lon / 10000000.0;
  zscale CONSTANT DOUBLE PRECISION := 2.0 ^ zoom;
  pi CONSTANT DOUBLE PRECISION := 3.141592653589793;
  r_per_d CONSTANT DOUBLE PRECISION := pi / 180.0;
  x int4;
  y int4;
BEGIN
  -- straight port of the C code. see db/functions/maptile.c
  x := floor((lon + 180.0) * zscale / 360.0);
  y := floor((1.0 - ln(tan(lat * r_per_d) + 1.0 / cos(lat * r_per_d)) / pi) * zscale / 2.0);

  RETURN (x << zoom) | y;
END;
```

So far I have:

```
 public const double pi = 3.141592653589793;
 public const double r_per_d = pi / 180.0;    

 public static long GetTile(double scaled_lat, double scaled_lon, int zoom)
 {
     double lat = scaled_lat / 10000000.0;
     double lon = scaled_lon / 10000000.0;
     return GetTile(lat, lon, zoom);
 }

 public static long GetTile(long lat, long lon, int zoom)
 {
     double zscale = Math.Pow(2.0, zoom);
     long x = (long)Math.Floor((lon + 180.0) * zscale / 360.0);
     long y = (long)Math.Floor((1.0 - Math.Log(Math.Tan(lat * r_per_d) + 1.0 / Math.Cos(lat * r_per_d)) / pi) * zscale / 2.0);
     return (x << zoom) | y;
 }
```

I call the function but loop through possible zoom values but none of them are matching the expected output.

Using data that's already in the table (526868344, -18000386) it should return 2062343892.

```
for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
{
    var r1 = NodeTileHelper.GetTile(526868344, -18000386, i);
    if (r1 == 2062343892)
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: fun fact: no need to declare your own [Pi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.math.pi?view=netcore-3.1) also: could you share some example inputs, expected outputs and actual outputs?

Comment: Have you compared results per every math function you use?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I added at the bottom the inputs and out. (526868344, -18000386) should return 2062343892. I'll add text to make it more clear.

Comment: The return value doesn't make a lot of sense in c# : return (x << zoom) | y;

Comment: I didn't find difference; https://dotnetfiddle.net/4U8y62 vs https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a5cd03e1ee5c6e7402451e9c8692dede though i did strip out the splitting of GetTile into two; couldn't work out why you'd done that - what value of zoom are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem might be how the method overloads are defined.

The following snippet of code is going to call the `GetTile(long, long, int)` overload, so it may not account for the scaling that is present in the other method.

```cs
NodeTileHelper.GetTile(526868344, -18000386, i);
```

In addition the following code in the scaling method recursively calls itself, because of the variable declarations. In order to account for the different method, you will need to convert `lat` and `lon` to `long` types.

```cs
double lat, lon;
// ...
return GetTile(lat, lon, zoom);
```

Given the original stored procedure definition, I think it would make more sense to consolidate this into one method instead of using overloads. Alternately, I think using different names for the methods would make it clearer than simply using the difference between parameter types (e.g,. `long` vs. `double`).